# when running npm install, I am getting error

Tags: npm-install

Getting below error while running npm install and not able to install any other package using npm
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@axe-devtools%2Fwebdriverio - Not Found
could anyone please tell me the solution?

I tried fix it by myself but no luck, still struggling to find the solution